# How to change the behavior of hyperlinks in generic inquiries

Tags: acumatica

In Generic Inquiries, I've noticed that certain fields automatically have hyperlink functionality to open specific screens.  I'm not sure what determines what screens these open (I'd imagine its based on whether its a key field for a maintenance table/DAC, etc.) - but I've also noticed that the manner in which it opens a screen is different for different fields / field types.  Some open a popup with no menu, others open in the same screen space as the Generic Inquiry, and in doing so replace it in the browser.

My question is this:   Is there a way to modify, in the GI setup, the manner in which it opens the screen so that it always opens as a replacement instead of a popup window?

Comment: Not sure about the GI question, but some detail on "not sure what determines what screens these open"... The DAC in the selector/segment most likely has a PXPrimaryGraph setup on the DAC as an attribute which points to a graph (or graphs depending on a set of conditions). Look at DAC PX.Objects.IN.INRegister for a good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, with Acumatica ERP ver. 6.0 on the Generic Inquiries' Navigation tab there was added Window Mode drop-down to configure how the screen is opened from hyperlinks in a given GI:

[image]